# how to covert array object to hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a hash with array object :

```
{
  false=>[#<Campaign id: 1, name: "campaign 1", active: false>, #<Campaign id: 3, name: "campaign 3", active: false>, #<Campaign id: 4, name: "campaign 4", active: false>], 
  true=>[#<Campaign id: 2, name: "campaign 2", active: true>]
}
```

how to convert  above hash to hash

```
{
  false=>[{id:1, name:"campaign 1"}, {id:3, name: "capaign 3"}, ....],
  true =>[{id:2, name:"campaign 2"}]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hash.each {|k,v| hash[k] = v.map{|e| {id: e[:id], name: e[:name]}}}
```

and if you can use `select_all` method get the array of hash, not array of object, so you doesn't need to covert object to hash.

```
ModelName.connection.select_all("select id, name from <table_name>;")
=> [{id:xxx, name: xxx}.......]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes) method on your object

> **attributes()** *public*
>
> Returns a hash of all the attributes with their names as keys and the values of the attributes as values.

```
hash = {
  false => [#<Campaign id: 1, name: "campaign 1", active: false>, #<Campaign id: 3, name: "campaign 3", active: false>, #<Campaign id: 4, name: "campaign 4", active: false>], 
  true  => [#<Campaign id: 2, name: "campaign 2", active: true>]
}
```

So this line should do the trick -

```
hash.each {|k, v| hash[k] = v.map(&:attributes) }

{
  false => [{"id": 1, "name": "campaign 1", "active": false}, {"id": 3, "name": "campaign 3", "active": false}, {"id": 4, "name": "campaign 4", "active": false}], 
  true  => [{"id": 2, "name": "campaign 2", "active": true}]
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".